# SQL Server script to summarize a stored procedure

Tags: sql-server

For a given stored procedure, I want the following summary -

- Tables selected with column names
- Tables modified (insert, update or delete) with column names (if update)
- Any child stored procedure being called with same summary as above two points.
- Parameters passed

Does anyone know such a T-SQL script to summarize a stored procedure?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `sp_help` to get information about with parameters and information about the object.

```
EXEC sp_help yourProcedure;
```

Then to get what it is using for tables and columns you can use `sp_depends`

```
EXEC sp_depends yourProcedure;
```

[Here](http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1294/listing-sql-server-object-dependencies/) is a useful link that list the sql Object Dependencies

Or you can also use. But it is only for 2008 and above.

```
SELECT * FROM sys.dm_sql_referenced_entities ('dbo.yourProcedure', 'OBJECT');
SELECT * FROM sys.dm_sql_referencing_entities('dbo.yourProcedure', 'OBJECT');
```

because `sp_depends` is deprecated.

If the store procedure are using dynamic sql. Then the only you have to use:

```
sp_helptext yourProcedure
```

This will return the content of the procedure.

If you have Dynamic sql in you store procedure. You could do something like this:

```
DECLARE @tbl TABLE(Text VARCHAR(MAX))
INSERT INTO @tbl
EXEC sp_helptext yourProcedure

SELECT 
    sysTables.name 
FROM 
    dbo.sysobjects AS sysTables
WHERE EXISTS
    (
        SELECT
            NULL
        FROM
            @tbl AS tbl
        WHERE
            tbl.Text LIKE '%'+sysTables.name+'%'
    )
```

This will return the objects used in the store procedure.

Comment: Is there a method to have it work out what are the used objects if proc contains dynamic SQL using these?

Comment: Yep, knew about the sp_helptext method. Was hoping there was a way to get around that. We are working on redoing an application that is rampant with dynamic SQL. Good to find out about the sp_depends method though. The sys.dm_sql_reference_* is available in SQL Server 2005?

Comment: Update the answer. You could do something like executing the sp_helptext asign it to a variable and the see which table names that contains. Maybe?

Comment: Was doing something like that already. Sometimes there are some false-positives due to column names and table names. Nature of the federal DB we use here. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

This will give you the actual text of the stored procedure which you can copy and paste into another query window and analyze.

```
sp_helptext yourProcedure
```